# Why did a green light appear white when looked out of the corner of my eye?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision, perception

The other day I saw a green light emitted from some source far away, and I realised that if I looked at it out of the corner of my eye I perceived it completely white. What is the explanation for this? Should this be more of a biology of the human eye question perhaps?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the physiology of the eye, not physics.

Comment: Was it at daytime or nighttime? What was the brightness of the source?

Comment: @RobJeffries surely someone can give me a physical explanation so as to why the physiology of the eye works in such interesting way

Comment: @Ruslan it was in the evening and the source was pretty bright :)

Comment: As to the why,  I believe evolution plays a role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://xkcd.com/1080/large/. Red and green-sensing cones are mostly found in the center of your visual field. Interestingly, this is not true for blue-sensing cones. It's also not true for rods, which detect black-and-white, so the reason the light appeared white is likely that it was picked up mostly by rods.